# Login application error with my fullstack vue express app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, vue.js, axios

I'm following a tutorial to create a full-stack register login application with vue.js in the front-end, express in the back-end and mongodb
whan I register a new user and login with it's email and password data the app works correctly, but when I enter data not found in the database the application behave like it's a registred user and move to the profile page and shows the Logout button.
here is the script of my Login.vue component

```
    <script>
import axios from 'axios'
import router from '../router'
import EventBus from './EventBus'
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    login () {
      axios.post('users/login', {
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password
      }).then(res => {
        localStorage.setItem('usertoken', res.data)
        this.email = ''
        this.password = ''
        router.push({ name: 'Profile' })
    this.emitMethod()
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })

    },
    emitMethod () {
      EventBus.$emit('logged-in', 'loggedin')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

the script of the Navbar.vue compenent

```
<script>
import EventBus from './EventBus'
EventBus.$on('logged-in', test => {
  console.log(test)
})
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      auth: '',
      user: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    logout () {
      localStorage.removeItem('usertoken')
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    EventBus.$on('logged-in', status => {
      this.auth = status
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

And here is the callback function for users router

```
    users.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({
        email: req.body.email
    })
        .then(user => {
            if (user) {
                if (bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password)) {
                    const payload = {
                        _id: user._id,
                        first_name: user.first_name,
                        last_name: user.last_name,
                        email: user.email
                    }
                    let token = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.SECRET_KEY, {
                        expiresIn: 1440
                    })
                    res.send(token)
                } else {
                    res.json({ error: 'User does not exist' })
                }
            } else {
                res.json({ error: 'User does not exist' })
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.send('error: ' + err)
        })
})
```

I wanna stop the app to set auth as 'loggedin' and display an error message if the user is not registred in the database

you cann find the full app in this link
https://github.com/ArjunAranetaCodes/MoreCodes-Youtube/tree/master/mevn-mongodb-login-reg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't specify a status code in the response, it will be 200 - OK by default.
So you client app thinks the login was succesfull even though the login was not successfull.

You need to specify status codes  when you return response in the bad cases.
for example not `res.json({ error: "User does not exist" });` but `res.status(400).json({ error: "User does not exist" });`

So your login route must be like this:

```js
users.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({
    email: req.body.email
  })
    .then(user => {
      if (user) {
        if (bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password)) {
          const payload = {
            _id: user._id,
            first_name: user.first_name,
            last_name: user.last_name,
            email: user.email
          };
          let token = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.SECRET_KEY, {
            expiresIn: 1440
          });
          res.send(token);
        } else {
          res.status(401).json({ error: "User does not exist" });
        }
      } else {
        res.status(401).json({ error: "User does not exist" });
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send("error: " + err);
    });
});
```

Here I send `401 - Unauthorized`  when the user is not found or when the password is wrong, but you may also consider to return `400 - Bad Request`.

Comment: @FaroukTurki you are welcome, can you also please upvote the answer?